# How to disallow user from customizing Cognos Workspace widgets layout?

Tags: dashboard, cognos

We are building a dashboard with Cognos workspace and wonder if it is possible to prohibit users from customizing their widgets ? We don't want them to move widgets or perform any customization. Can we do that ? It's best if we can remove all customization toolbars (both at the top of widgets and at the top of page)

Thanks.

[image: Dashboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set this up in Administration->Security->Capabilities

The user should have access to 'Executive Dashboard'

But if you click on Executive Dashboard you have access to customize certain features within it.

'Use Advanced Dashboard Features'

and

'Use Interactive Dashboard Features'.

Always make sure you check your licenses before opening up new capabilities for your users.

Also, consider setting the Workspace Page itself as Read Only for the users.  Then if they decide to change things, they will be unable to save any changes.  They can always save a copy of it in their personal 'My Folders', but that will not affect the other report consumers.